# Should an azure Notification hub client be a singleton?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

When using notification hubs on a web server, is it recommended to create a singleton client instance or to create a new client for each group of messages sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notification Hub client is a very light weight http wrapper. There is no requirement to be a singleton.

Thanks,

Sateesh